# Can anyone provide me the correct Intel HD Graphics driver link?

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, intel-graphics, display-driver, x86

I am knowing that many users will find this question funny as I can't even find the correct driver but the question is somehow complicated. My device is Asus x200ma. Manufacturer's driver is only made for Windows 8.1 64bit or x64. But the problem now is I have installed Windows 7 ultimate 32bit x86. I don't want any other driver. I want only two drivers: VGA driver and Intel HD Graphics driver. I am giving the netbook's details below. I can't provide any screenshot as i don't have that much reputations. Again, highliting the main question:

> Download link for VGA and Intel HD Graphics driver for Asus x200ma.

**Netbook details:-**

**Manufacturer**: AsusTek©

**Processor**: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2920 @ 1.86GHz  1.86 GHz

**Installed memory (RAM)**: 2.00 GB (1.89 GB usable)

**System type**: 32-bit Operating System

**Graphics Adapter info:**

**Chip Type**: Intel(R) VLV Mobile/Desktop Graphics Chipset

**DAC Type**: 8 bit

**Adapter string**: VGA

**Bios Information**: Hardware Version 0.0

**GRAPHICS INFO:**

**Total Available Graphics Memory**: 63424 KB

**Dedicated Video Memory**: n/a

**System Video Memory**: n/a

**Shared Video Memory**: n/a

Again highliting question:

> Download link for VGA and Intel HD Graphics

Thanks for viewing. If any additional information is required, comment it below. Please help me.

Comment: go to http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-011363.htm, and run the applet. it will detect the driver required, and offer to install it for you.

Comment: I don't trust private cloud based storage accounts.  [Here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=N2920) is the driver you want.  Since the answer to this question is only a link I won't be submitting an answer.  [Here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/24972/Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-8-1-32-bit?httpDown=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F24972%2Fa08%2Fwin32_153336.exe) is a direct link to the June 2015 driver.  This is the only drive you need to acomplish your goal(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on 7-8 of these exact series of computers so I did a direct backup of the Intel HD Graphics driver. Here's a [link](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9yjt92pgd0th4/Asus_Intel_Graphics_Driver) to my upload of it.

The reason it's better than going through the manufacturer's website is many drivers (understandably) cross reference your O.S. to make sure your installing the proper driver. So when you manually install an O.S. and the manuf. doesn't offer support for it, it can get tricky.

That being said, I used [DoubleDriver](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/double_driver.html) to backup the Graphics Driver. You can also use it to restore/import the driver by just pointing it to the folder. Otherwise if you go into `devmgmt.msc` (Device Manager) you can right click on graphics driver and manually point it to the same folder. It will be able to figure out the rest using the `.ini` files.

EDIT: Updated with a better download link. https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9yjt92pgd0th4/Asus_Intel_Graphics_Driver

Comment: Okay, just checking it. If it works, then I got my answer.

Comment: Hey BiTinerary, the link you provided is of Google drive and it is saying that i need permission to access. Please grant it.

Comment: Will do. Just download the whole folder, as opposed to individual files. Also, I will be uploading it to MediaFire so that I can provide a better/direct download link.

Comment: I knew it would! Good to hear. I wonder why I've gotten so many downvotes from my answer though...

Comment: I can't upvote due to lack of reputation. I have something to ask! Do you only have graphics driver? I mean camera driver is also needed!! Can you provide it?

Comment: I've got all the drivers, yes. I'll get you the one for the camera in just a little while.

Comment: Leave the camera! I've fixed it myself! Just provide me the package of all drivers. Can you do that? If no, then I request you to provide Bluetooth driver because now I'm working on it!!

Comment: Here's a direct link to all the drivers (Both non Microsoft **and** MicroSoft) it's less than 100MB and zipped so it shouldn't be a big deal. I recommend using DoubleDriver to import them if you haven't been already. http://www.mediafire.com/download/871trw39gzcyc87/AllAsusX200Drivers.zip

Comment: Bro! But it doesn't contain Bluetooth driver!

Comment: Sorry man. I literally backed up all of the drivers that were available on that computer. That specific computer must not have had bluetooth capabilities. I would suggest getting all the MicroSoft updates for your computer, there's a chance that they will find/update with the right ones.

Comment: Ok,! Should try that method. But it has Bluetooth capability because the manufacturer declares it.